# Same hardware id using C# WMI with acronis image

Tags: c#, security, wmi

Using C#, querying WMI for hardware unique ID, and get pc image using acronis true image to recover another pc i found that the same hardware id returned when querying WMI .. how to resolve this issue to get a proper unique ID for each pc ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Unique ID" that you can look for. Evenry ID is hardware dependant and for that reason if you replace for example your processor, that unique ID will change. The same runs for memory, disk drives and so. You will have to look what is the real concept of "uniqueness" that you want to achieve. You might want to create a hash combining several keys.

Nevertheless, If you want to access WMI and generate some sort of key, you can use [ORMI](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) that will help you to get the results you need. I would go for something like this:

Use the library:

```
using ORMi;
```

Then query:

```
var processors = helper.Query("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");

foreach(var v in processors)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v.ProcessorID);
}
```